# NHibernate Hierarchical Master Details QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Hi gyus
I'm writing here so....I've a problem :-)
Here my situation:

Table A (Category) {ID, List, List }
Table B (CategoryLanguage) {IDCategory, IDLanguage, Description}
Table C (SubCategory) {IDCategory, ID, List }
Table D (SubCategoryLanguage) {IDSubCategory, IDLanguage, Description}

Here my QueryOver (with Aliases) code

```
Category Cat = null;
CategoryLanguage catLang = null;
SubCategory subCat = null;
SubCategoryLanguage subCatLang = null;                        

var qOver = _HibSession.QueryOver<Category>(() => Cat)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => Cat.Languages, () => catLang)
        .Where(() => catLang.IDLanguage == IDLanguage)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => Cat.SubCategories, () => subCat)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => subCat.Languages, () => subCatLang)
            .Where(() => subCatLang.IDLanguage == IDLanguage)
    .OrderBy(() => Cat.ID).Asc
    .List<Category>();
```

With this Query, NHibernate doesn't filter the Languages fields and when I loop into the subCategories (to print out on my view the tree Category=>SubCategory ) it launches a Query for every subCategory!! (I saw it using NHibernate Profiler)
I don't use Lazy Loading but using JoinAlias I expected to see all data joined.

Anyone can help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but in some of the queries I've created using QueryOver I've specified the fetch mode e.g.

```
Category Cat = null;
CategoryLanguage catLang = null;
SubCategory subCat = null;
SubCategoryLanguage subCatLang = null;                        

var qOver = _HibSession.QueryOver<Category>(() => Cat)
.Left.JoinAlias(() => Cat.Languages, () => catLang)
.Fetch(x => x.Languages).Eager
    .Where(() => catLang.IDLanguage == IDLanguage)
.Left.JoinAlias(() => Cat.SubCategories, () => subCat)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => subCat.Languages, () => subCatLang)
.Fetch(x => x.SubCategories).Eager
        .Where(() => subCatLang.IDLanguage == IDLanguage)
.OrderBy(() => Cat.ID).Asc
.List<Category>();
```

Comment: I've tried to add the Fetch code, but the result is the same. I can't filter the Details table so my object has multiple no filtred contents. Could be lazy loading the right solution?